# How to make a scrollable flexbox that has two divs of the screen size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a flexbox containing two divs that divides the screen as equals. When the screen gets smaller than 800px, i want the flexbox direction to change from row to column and each div to have the size of the screen, making the flexbox div scrollable, how to do that? 
My actual code is:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="pt-br">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="left">

  </div>
  <div id="right">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make body height **auto** and add this CSS (making each div full screen height):

```
 #left,#right {
    height:100vh;
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
    height:auto;
  }
  #left,#right {
    height:100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="left">

  </div>
  <div id="right">

  </div>
</body>
```

Or make the height of body equal to **2x100vh=200vh** so that each div will take the **half** (100vh) since you set `flex:1` on both:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
    height:200vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="left">

  </div>
  <div id="right">

  </div>
</body>
```

Or make the height of body equal to **2x100%** which will also be the same as **2x100vh** in your case:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
    height:200%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="left">

  </div>
  <div id="right">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! I'm not used to use these CSS units like "vh" but they are so useful. I must practice this.

Comment: @Pedroleal you can also continue using % i added the third way in my answer ;)

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you again!